# Proposed new StackExchange site: RantOverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, rant

There seem to be a lot of questions asked on SO ([last example here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337927/how-much-is-too-much-for-a-lone-developer) which are rants/cries-of-the-soul/shrieks-in-the-void etc... Most of them are career related (D'uh).

A vast majority are, of course, closed as "Not a real question"/"Not programming related"/"Subjective" - mostly, for a good reason.

Yet, I find myself reading many of them with at least some interest and at times answering as they ARE worthy of answers/discussion - though not on SO. But they don't belong on Meta either as they are not about SO. Heck, sometimes I wish I could post a rant or two - but I refuse to do so on SO as it'd be hypocritical of me as closer of many such rants and against the site rules.

Did anyone consider creating RantOverflow? (I was thinking DailyWTF as a substitute, but that has a lot less useful/nice interface and infrastracture as SO engine.

Comment: Whether someone else has made one or not is irrelevant, go make one.

Comment: @Polyanna - Was that an offer to seed the capital required to run such a site? :)

Comment: Would programmers SE fit the bill?

Comment: @Andrew - beats me, I didn't hang out on PSE long enough to know the full rules yet. But it's lots closer than SO, that's for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure about RantOverflow, but I'm regularly seeing questions that would have their place on some kind of *AskTheDeveloppersFlow*-like web-site.

i.e. questions that are asking for opinion of some fellow peers -- not programming-related, but programmers-related.

Comment: +1 It would have to be named "the pub."